# What's the difference between using global variables and Queue Class for thread data communication in Python?

Tags: python, queue, python-multithreading

I would like to know when to use **Queue class** in Python during multi-thread communication situations since many stack overflow posts are suggesting. For Queue class, one can use queue.put(var) in one thread for putting data to the queue and use queue.get() in another thread for getting data out of the queue.

Why can't I just declare a **global variable** for both threads. One modifying it while another one accessing it?

Also, if queue class is recommended, why do people use **dequeue class** instead under some conditions?

Comment: what order will the threads access the global variable in? will they both try to access it at the same time? global variables are not "thread safe" as a concept. Although you can get away with it in cpython, the most common python interpreter used by default, which will ensure only 1 thread can access the variable at a time, (meaning they are thread safe in cpython) it is not a good habit to rely on it.

Comment: You should avoid global variables in general. They introduce strange errors, the code is difficult to test and hard to read.

Comment: @Daniel Is it correct if I put it in this way: When using global variable for thread-communication, I have to deal with locking mechanism to ensure the global variable is not being written and read from multiple threads at the same time. Whereas using Queue module, instead of using locking, the only limitation is threads can not write to queue when it's full.

Comment: @ctheadn8954: you should avoid global variables in general, there is no excuse to use them. Queues can have infinite length and if the length is limited, the thread is paused, till there is room again.

Comment: @daniel, every example of queues and threads has the queue being a global.  Is that just for simplicity of the example?  if so, where is it declared and how does each thread know about it?